# Is it more secure to ask only for the username before the password?

Tags: authentication

The traditional login page has two fields: username and password. But some sites, notably Google and Amazon, first ask for the username and only later provide a password field, placing each field on its own page. Is this design choice motivated by a security point of view? If so, why is that?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85160/is-having-the-username-and-password-fields-on-different-pages-more-secure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is having the username and password fields on different pages more secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85160/is-having-the-username-and-password-fields-on-different-pages-more-secure), [Why do some sites ask for username/email and password on two separate screens?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160692/why-do-some-sites-ask-for-username-email-and-password-on-two-separate-screens).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich my question is definitely a dupe of the second one you suggested. Thanks.